# I need to update my jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, navigation

I got a piece of code from CSSTRICKS, the magic line navigation, which will put a line under my menu items, and will move over the ones I hover. I want it to be like this, when I click the menus, the line will be staying at that menu item, and not go back to the first one as usual.

The script uses a class selector to tell where the line should go by default. With that, I did an toggleClass with jQuery, which passes the class to the clicked menu item, but it doesn't update. I have to reload the page in order to update. And, again, it is stuck in the same position. I hope somebody knows how to do this. Here is my code:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    var $el, leftPos, newWidth;
    $mainNav2 = $("#example-two");

    /*
    EXAMPLE ONE
*/

    /* Add Magic Line markup via JavaScript, because it ain't gonna work without */
    $("#line-menu").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

    /* Cache it */
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine.width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".active a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#line-menu li").find("a").hover(function () {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();

        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function () {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: create a live demo in jsfiddle.net, very hard to help without being able to see positioning issues with live html and css

Comment: The part within `$("#line-menu li").find("a").hover(function () {` is the part that sets you magic line's position (and the second function below it realigns it back to it's origin). The class itself is only part of it, and getting it setup to stay under the active menu item is a little bit more than just adding that class to the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move magicline to it's own function. Edits are commented below.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        magicline();
    });

function magicline() {

    var $el, leftPos, newWidth,
        $mainNav = $("#example-one");
    //remove the old magic line before creating a new one.
    $("#magic-line").remove();
    $mainNav.append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");

    $magicLine
        .width($(".current_page_item").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_page_item a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

    $("#example-one li a").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this);
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        });
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        });    
    });
}
//on click on a new menu item iterate through and remove the class
//then add the class back to the parent of the a clicked and recall the 
//magicline function
$('li a').on('click',function(){
    $('li').each(function(){ 
       $(this).removeClass('current_page_item');               
    });
    $(this).parent().addClass('current_page_item');
    magicline();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/vtuKH/1/

PS. I used the code from CSSTRICKS, you'll have to change the id's to match your id's.

Comment: It worked well on the jsfiddle, but I am a noob I couldn't integrate well with my site, I don't know why. Anyways, somebody else gave me a simpler answer, thanks a lot both of you.

Answer (score 1):

I more or less guess at the CSS and markup, but this is much more concise:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    var $lineMenu = $("#line-menu"),
        $active = $lineMenu.children('.current_page_item'),
        $magicLine = $("<li id='magic-line'></li>");

    $magicLine
        .width($active.width())
        .css("left", $active.position().left)
        .appendTo($lineMenu);

    $lineMenu.on('mouseenter mouseleave click', 'li:not(#line-menu)', function (e) {
        var $el = e.type == 'mouseleave' ? $active : $(this);

        if (e.type == 'click') {
            $el.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            $active = $el;
        } else {
            $magicLine.stop().animate({
                left: $el.position().left,
                width: $el.width()
            });
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/tTsk6/

Comment: Thanks a ton man, this one worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

That line comes back to origional position because, there's callback attached to `hover`. What you need to do in this case is, when menu item is clicked, you need to avoid that line to go to origional position.

Here's what I'd do -

Attach click handler, when user clicks menu item set up a flag to show that menu is selected. Check this flag in callback function of hover, if set then return. Else if not flat set, take line to previous position.

```
var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");
var isClicked = false;  // to show whether menu is clicked or not

$magicLine.width($(".current_page_item").width())
    .css("left", $(".active a").position().left)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());

$("#line-menu li").find("a").hover(function () {
    $el = $(this);
    leftPos = $el.position().left;
    newWidth = $el.parent().width();

    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
}, function () {
   if(!isClicked){         // if no item is clicked, take line to old position
      $magicLine.stop().animate({
          left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
          width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
      });
    }else{                 // else, just keep it there  
       isClicked = false;
       return false;
    }
}).click(function(e){   // added click listener 
    isClicked = true;       // flag is set to indicate menu item is clicked.
    $magicLine.css({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });                             
});
```

First, i thought about `unbinding hover` would prevent callback being called but that didn't worked out. So tried it with flags. Please, read code comments, i didn't put everything in answer.